# Intermittend DB service error (Ec2+RDS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, rds, mysql5.6

I have a EC2 Ubuntu server with the database as RDS. It is connecting fine and the db connections are low but intermittently showing a DB service error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

I have tried adding Google DNS and it still persist

Comment: I'm seeing this as well (mysql, fwiw), did OP ever resolve?